# Create claim not working in "Proof of Existence" tutorial

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template, substrate-front-end

I'm at the very last stage of [this tutorial to make a custom pallet](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/use-macros-in-a-custom-pallet/#build-a-custom-front-end-component) and have tried running Substrate frontend template in my browser. I'm using [this code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/teamchong/substrate-proof-of-existence-frontend/main/src/TemplateModule.js) for TemplateModule.js, but when I try to create a new claim I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
```

On the line where it says:

```
api.query.templateModule
      .proofs(digest, result => {
        // Our storage item returns a tuple, which is represented as an array.
        setOwner(result[0].toString()) // <--- THIS LINE GIVES ME AN ERROR
        setBlock(result[1].toNumber())
      })
      .then(unsub => {
        unsubscribe = unsub
      })
```

And the result is that I'm not able to create a proof of existence claim. Any idea how to fix this?

This is the `result` object by the way:
[image]

Comment: Looks like result is undefined, maybe check if result is not empty ?

Comment: I've posted what my result looks like in the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error appears because before add any claim is trying to get the owner and block from an undefined value.

It has to be checked if this value exists before trying to get the owner and the block:

```
if(result.value[0] && result.value[1]){
   setOwner(result.value[0].toString())
   setBlock(result.value[1].toNumber())
}
```

The fix has been proposed for the documentation tutorial code [here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-docs/pull/1356)